# postgres - regex_replace in distinct clause?

Tags: regex, postgresql, replace, whitespace

Ok... changing the question here...  I'm getting an error when I try this:

```
SELECT COUNT ( DISTINCT mid, regexp_replace(na_fname, '\\s*', '', 'g'), regexp_replace(na_lname, '\\s*', '', 'g'))
FROM masterfile;
```

Is it possible to use regexp in a distinct clause like this?

The error is this:

```
WARNING:  nonstandard use of \\ in a string literal
LINE 1: ...CT COUNT ( DISTINCT mid, regexp_replace(na_fname, '\\s*', ''...
```

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. To indicate that a string literal is using \ to escape special characters, use an `E` before the string literal.

Comment: My bad... You'd think the WARNING would have tipped me off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select trim(regexp_replace(E'\tfoo  \t bar  baz   ', E'\\s+', ' ', 'g'))
```

replaces all (due to the `'g'` flag) whitespace (`\s`) sequences (`+`) with a single space, then trims it, returning:

```
"foo bar baz"
```

The `E` is to indicate that the `\` escape encoding is used.

With your new, edited question, you're probably looking for a query along the lines of:

```
select count(*) from (
    select distinct 
        mid, 
        regexp_replace(na_fname, E'\\s*', '', 'g'), 
        regexp_replace(na_lname, E'\\s*', '', 'g') 
    from masterfile) as subquery;
```

Comment: Thanks for this... I did figure this part out... I'm trying to do a count distinct (I edited my original question).  Any suggestions on how to do that?  I tried doing it as a select count(*) where mid in ( select count ( distinct ... ), but I get "subquery has too many columns"...

Comment: Thank you again.  I'm a bit out of my depth with pg, so I appreciate the guidance